# Compute date difference with amp-date-picker

Tags: amp-html, amp-date-picker

I want to update a value according to the selected range in the date picker. This means, if I am staying from the 8th to the 11th, it should say 3 nights. If the dates are modified, this value should update accordingly. Working on a little [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/obek7fLh/1/):

```html
    <p>Choose your travel dates</p>
    <div class="align-content-center space-between">
      <div class="ampstart-input">
        <input class="border-none p0" id="lb-start" placeholder="Start date" on="tap:lb.open" role="textbox" tabindex="0">
      </div>
      <div class="ampstart-input">
        <input class="border-none p0" id="lb-end" placeholder="End date" on="tap:lb.open" role="textbox" tabindex="0">
      </div>
      <button class="ampstart-btn caps" on="tap:lb-picker.clear">Clear</button>
    </div>
    <amp-lightbox id="lb" layout="nodisplay">
      <button class="ampstart-btn absolute m1 caps small-button" on="tap:lb.close" tabindex="0">Close</button>
      <div class="align-content-center">
        <amp-date-picker id="lb-picker" type="range" mode="static" layout="fixed-height" height="360" format="MM/DD/YYYY" on="activate: lb.open;
              deactivate: lb.close;" start-input-selector="#lb-start" end-input-selector="#lb-end"></amp-date-picker>
      </div>
    </amp-lightbox>
<p>Total nights: </p>
```

It is a very common feature when selecting dates in travel pages but I could not find any real example of it. If the date picker does not support something like this, can I achieve this behavior with [JS expressions](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind#expressions)?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use the `select` event:

```
<amp-date-picker on="select: AMP.setState({nights: event.dates.length})">
```

More info [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/17409). Thanks